# Multiwebsite delete data

Tags: magento-1.9, websites

I have 3 websites in one Magento installation.

I have deleted 2 websites.

Now how do I delete more data from database to reduce my db size?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the data should be deleted nicely because almost all the tables that have a FK to the store view table have `on delete cascade`.
Only the orders/invoices/shipments/credit memos should not be deleted because you don't want that.
Just check the tables that start with `catalog_product_entity_*` to see if you have zombie data in them. This means you need to check if you still have records with `store_id` one of the store views you already delete.
Also check the `core_config_data` for records with `scope = website and scope_id = {ids of websites you deleted}` or  `scope = stores and scope_id = {ids of websites you deleted}`

Comment: I think we should also delete flat tables like catalog_product_flat_2, catalog_category_flat_store_2 etc. manually.

Comment: Right. I forgot about the flat tables.

Comment: direct on live?

Comment: And make a backup first :) If you screw up while deleting, you might get problems with foreign keys, which will lead to further problems when you try to insert new rows in those tables.

Comment: Test it first on a separate environment. Clone your db an clean up the clone to see who it goes.

Comment: actually my searching very slow so i supposed that its because of multi store?

Comment: could be, but the search index is build based on the store views you have active. If you deleted the stores, the search index for the store should be deleted automatically.